# Flask: display newly generated image on webpage while continuing with function?

Tags: python, flask

I have a webpage where the user uploads an image and my python code will make some adjustments to it and do some analysis. I want the newly generated image to be displayed to the user on the webpage as soon as it's generated, and then continue doing the analysis that needs to be done, and then update the webpage with that information. However, I am not sure how to communicate from flask to the webpage halfway through the function (once the new image is generated) that the website can display the newly generated image, as using `render_template` can only be done at the end of the function.

My python (flask) code is as follows:

```
@app.route('/uploaded', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            f = request.files['file']
            f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
            image = cv2.imread(filename)
            im = Image.fromarray(image)
            # make some adjustments to the image (not shown here) and then save it...
            im.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'your_file.jpg'))
            # after the new image is generated, display it on the website at {{ place_for_generated_image }}
            # do some more analysis, then finally:
            return render_template('index.html', analysis = analysis)
```

HTML is straightforward:

```
<form action = "http://localhost/uploaded" method = "POST" 
            enctype = "multipart/form-data">
            <input type = "file" name = "file" class="form-control-file">
            <input type = "submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Upload Image" button id="uploadfile" onclick="uploadfile()">
            </form>
            {{ place_for_generated_image }}
            {{ analysis }}
```

Comment: It seems you need to process your image asynchronously, maybe try using a task queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use multiple ajax calls to achieve that. Something like the below:

First make a route to handle the image upload

```
@app.route('/uploaded', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            f = request.files['file']
            f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
            image = cv2.imread(filename)
            im = Image.fromarray(image)
            # make some adjustments to the image (not shown here) and then save it...
            im.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'your_file.jpg'))
            # Here you need to convert your image to a base64 string and return that string to your ajax call
            # do some more analysis, then finally:
            return 'YOUR BASE64 ENCODED IMAGE STRING'
```

This route will handle your analysis. Your second nested ajax call will communicate with this route
from flask import Response

```
@app.route('/analyze', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def analyze():
        # run some analysis
        return Response(status=200, response="Anlysis Done")
```

This what your javascript code should look like. You can place it in a script tag in your template. If you place it in a separate JS file, make sure to look at my comment for the url_for in the second ajax call

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function(res){
        // Here you write code that will display the returned base64 image 
        // from the upload_file route Just update your img tag src to the 
        // base64 string you received as the response

        // SECOND AJAX CALL TO RUN THE ANALYTICS 
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{url_for('analysis')}}", // if this JS code in a separate JS file you will have to declare a URL variable in a script tag in your template as {{url_for}} is only accessible from your template 
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'any data you want to send can be in JSON format' 
        }).done(function(res){
            // analysis is done 
        })
    })
})
```